# Query performance question

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, partitioning, performance, performance-tuning, query-performance

Using Demo from [here](https://dbafromthecold.com/2014/06/04/partitioning-basics-part-1/) to reproduce my issue with changes in table structure as below and modifying demo partition function to datetime

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DemoPartitionedTable](
    [DemoID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [SomeData] [sysname] NOT NULL,
    [CaptureDate] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_DemoPartitionedTable] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [DemoID] ASC,
    [CaptureDate] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
)
GO
```

Users run query like below (Query 1)

```
SELECT [DemoID], [SomeData], [CaptureDate] FROM    
[dbo].[DemoPartitionedTable] WHERE (1=1) and (1=1) and    
CONVERT(varchar(10),CaptureDate,112) between 20190912 and 20190912
```

Plan is https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=r1veZhovH

> Takes about 4 hours to return 5 million rows

To improve above code if i used partition key as below (Query 2)

```
 SELECT [DemoID], [SomeData], [CaptureDate] FROM        
 [dbo].[DemoPartitionedTable] WHERE (1=1) and (1=1) and        
 CaptureDate>= cast('2019-09-12' as date) and         
 CaptureDate< cast('2019-09-13' as date)
```

> This completes in around 40 minutes

PLan for this https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=BkDYl3svB

Now if i run below, it completes in 10 minutes and scan directly the specific partition of the day as required compared to first 2 queries which scanned all the partitions (Query 3)

```
SELECT [DemoID],
       [SomeData],
       [CaptureDate]
FROM [dbo].[DemoPartitionedTable]
WHERE (1=1)
  AND (1=1)
  AND $partition.DemoPartitionFunction(CaptureDate)>=$partition.DemoPartitionFunction('09/12/2019')
  AND $partition.DemoPartitionFunction(CaptureDate)<$partition.DemoPartitionFunction('09/13/2019')
```

PLan https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=S1j9CjsPB

The problem with above is users have to find the PF name before querying as used in my query 3. Why cant query 2 perform similar to query and make use of partition elimination? Is there a way query can be coded to find PF name rather than hard coding in query ?

Please advise

Comment: @PaulWhite, I agree. I am working on it to reproduce using stack overflow database, no luck. Will use the link given by you, thanks

Comment: Thats true. Query 1 of user had implicit conversion warnings (partkey is a datetime column) while query 2 and 3 did not. Let me set up and update the question

Comment: @PaulWhite-- Updated with demo db and try to reproduce somewhat same plan. Just the amount of data and number of columns are different but overall plan looks same. Hope this helps

Comment: What is the implementation of `DemoPartitionFunction`?

Comment: https://dbafromthecold.com/2014/06/04/partitioning-basics-part-1/ from here

Comment: @PaulWhite: Thanks, i updated the changes i made to demo to make structure what i have here  . It should make more sense now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The table in the question isn't partitioned. I assume the intended definitions are:

```
CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION DemoPartitionFunction (datetime)
AS RANGE RIGHT
FOR VALUES (DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETUTCDATE()), -7),
            DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETUTCDATE()), -6),
            DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETUTCDATE()), -5),
            DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETUTCDATE()), -4),
            DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETUTCDATE()), -3),
            DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETUTCDATE()), -2),
            DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETUTCDATE()), -1),
            DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETUTCDATE()), 0),
            DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETUTCDATE()), 1),
            DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETUTCDATE()), 2),
            DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETUTCDATE()), 3),
            DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETUTCDATE()), 4),
            DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETUTCDATE()), 5),
            DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETUTCDATE()), 6),
            DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETUTCDATE()), 7));

CREATE PARTITION SCHEME DemoPartitionScheme
AS PARTITION DemoPartitionFunction
ALL TO ([DEFAULT]);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DemoPartitionedTable](
    [DemoID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [SomeData] [sysname] NOT NULL,
    [CaptureDate] [datetime] NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_DemoPartitionedTable] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
    (
        [DemoID] ASC,
        [CaptureDate] ASC
    )
    ON DemoPartitionScheme(CaptureDate)
) ON DemoPartitionScheme(CaptureDate);
```

#### Query 1

```
SELECT [DemoID], [SomeData], [CaptureDate] FROM    
[dbo].[DemoPartitionedTable] WHERE (1=1) and (1=1) and    
CONVERT(varchar(10),CaptureDate,112) between 20190912 and 20190912
```

Aside from the redundant `1=1` predicates, the date comparison is a mess of mismatched types. The `datetime` column *CaptureDate* is converted to `varchar(10)` without an explicit style, then compared to `integers`.

The residual predicate on the heap scan reflects this confusion:

```
CONVERT_IMPLICIT(int,CONVERT(varchar(10),[dbo].[DemoPartitionedTable].[CaptureDate],112),0)>=(20190912) 
AND CONVERT_IMPLICIT(int,CONVERT(varchar(10),[dbo].[DemoPartitionedTable].[CaptureDate],112),0)<=(20190912)
```

These predicates cannot use an index, nor do they help SQL Server with partition elimination.

#### Query 2

```
SELECT [DemoID], [SomeData], [CaptureDate] FROM        
 [dbo].[DemoPartitionedTable] WHERE (1=1) and (1=1) and        
 CaptureDate>= cast('2019-09-12' as date) and         
 CaptureDate< cast('2019-09-13' as date)
```

This is a little better. It avoids converting the columns, but for some reason chooses to compare the `datetime` *CaptureDate* column with a `date` data type. These are different data types. There isn't a warning about type conversion in the plan because SQL Server can convert the `date` typed literals to `datetime` during compilation. Nevertheless, the type inconsistency is enough to prevent partition elimination.

#### Writing the query correctly

```
SELECT
    DPT.DemoID,
    DPT.SomeData,
    DPT.CaptureDate
FROM dbo.DemoPartitionedTable AS DPT
WHERE 
    1 = 1
    AND DPT.CaptureDate >= CONVERT(datetime, '20190912', 112)
    AND DPT.CaptureDate < CONVERT(datetime, '20190913', 112);
```

The above query compares the `datetime` *CaptureDate* column with a `datetime` literal. Notice the use of an explicit style, so SQL Server knows the format of the string. You should generally prefer `CONVERT` with the correct style to `CAST` when working with dates and times.

The `1 = 1` predicate is there to avoid simple parameterization.

This query allows SQL Server to perform partition elimination, as shown by the *Seek Predicate* on the heap table:

```
Seek Keys[1]: Prefix: PtnId1001 = Scalar Operator((1))
```

There is still a residual predicate applied to each row in the partition:

```
[dbo].[DemoPartitionedTable].[CaptureDate] as [DPT].[CaptureDate]>='2019-09-12 00:00:00.000'
AND [dbo].[DemoPartitionedTable].[CaptureDate] as [DPT].[CaptureDate]<'2019-09-13 00:00:00.000'
```

This is because the table lacks a covering index with *CaptureDate* as the leading key. If you want the query to be as fast as possible, you should create an index like that.

For more details please see my article [Why Doesn’t Partition Elimination Work?](https://www.sql.kiwi/2012/09/why-doesn-t-partition-elimination-work.html)

Please pay careful attention to data types when writing queries.